# Running ModelControllerClient in a Batch

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm accessing the Wildfly CLI through the Java API using the `ModelControllerClient` (and the `ServerDeploymentManager`).

I'd like to run my changes as a CLI batch, but can't find an API for that.

Simply executing `new ModelNode().get("operation").set("batch");` throws a `WFLYCTL0031: No operation named 'batch' exists at address []`.

Maybe the `batch` command is like the other 'convenience methods' like `data-source add`, etc.? How would I execute those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `batch` operation, it's a CLI command only. The `ModelControllerClient` accepts DMR operations. CLI converts commands into DMR operations. What you're looking for is a composite operation.

There is a helper in the in the `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller-client` dependency. Here's an example of using the `CompositeOperationBuilder`.

```java
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient;
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.Operation;
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.Operations.CompositeOperationBuilder;
import org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode;

public class ExampleOperation {

    public ModelNode executeCompositeOperation(final ModelControllerClient client, final ModelNode... ops) throws IOException {
        final CompositeOperationBuilder builder = CompositeOperationBuilder.create(true);
        for (ModelNode op : ops) {
            builder.addStep(op);
        }
        final ModelNode result = client.execute(builder.build());
        if (!Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
        }
        return Operations.readResult(result);
    }
}
```

If you're also using the `ServerDeploymentManager` there is a [newish API](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/tree/master/core) which that has a few more options. It's what the `wildfly-maven-plugin` uses internally and it's now just a separate module so others can consume it.